# How to transfer 2 Enumerable collections to 1 ObservableCollectionsList?

Tags: c#

This is a complete Newbie question and I understand but how do I transfer these two distinct Enumerable collections to a single ObservableCollections?

```
  var distinctLine1 = (from z in list
                            orderby z.ItemLine1
                            select z.ItemLine1).Distinct();
        var distinctLine2 = (from z in list
                            orderby z.ItemLine2
                            select z.ItemLine2).Distinct();
        foreach (var item in distinctLine1)
        {

        }
```

Sorry did change ObservableCollectionsList to ObservableCollections

ItemLine1 and ItemLine2 are both strings

Comment: As long as they're `IEnumerable` of the same type, you can join them into a single enumerable with `distinctLine1.Concat(distinctLine2)`. I don't know what an `ObservableCollectionsList` is. Did you mean `ObservableCollection`? If so, this constructor is the one you'll want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx

Comment: What type of ItemLine1 and ItemLine2 properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you could probabl also call `Distinct` on union to exclude possible duplicates.

```
var union = distinctLine1.Union(distinctLine2).Distinct();
```

Or just

```
var union = distinctLine1.Union(distinctLine2);
```

And then simply create the target collection with [ObservableCollection Constructor (IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169.aspx):

```
var result = new ObservableCollection<string>(union);
```